# Always loaded components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a simple site here: https://core.mdcholewka.now.sh/ when I'm switching pages, the API is fetching and the Navbar component and Sidebar component is loading again. I won't it to don't load again. Can I do this?

Comment: Can you post your source code?

Comment: https://github.com/silvestris-software/core

Comment: You can make a PR if you want.

Comment: In first look, can you change sidebar functional component to const MySidebar = React.memo(Sidebar) and export it or convert it to class purecomponent

Comment: Done. Can I do the same for Navbar?

Comment: And what now? Did you test sidebar?

Comment: Sidebar seems to be loaded any time, but the API is fetching again when I switch page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200317/discussion-between-oleg-and-cholewka).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by myself. Just needed to  add `dynamic()` from `next/dynamic` and add custom `_document`. [I've deployed it to Now](https://nextjs-memo.mdcholewka.now.sh) for a better POV, and [it's in my repo](https://github.com/Cholewka/nextjs-component-memo), too.